# Generating frequencies from CSV file

Tags: r

I want to generate a frequency table of values, but so far I only found how to do that by making classes, I want non-grouped values. Let's say i have:

```
values <- c(1,2,5,6,3,4,3,2,6,7)
```

how to generate a frequency table out of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `table`

```
> tab <- table(values)
values
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 2 1 1 2 1
```

if you prefer a data.frame

```
> as.data.frame(tab)
  values Freq
1      1    1
2      2    2
3      3    2
4      4    1
5      5    1
6      6    2
7      7    1
```

Plotting:

```
hist(values)  # histogram of `values`
plot(tab)     # plot of `tab`, table of frequencies
barplot(tab)  # plot of `tab`, table of frequencies
```

Comment: how to depict that to a histogram now? :(

Comment: take a look at `hist` function. Start by reading the help file. [This is a good place to start with](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html)

Comment: one last thing, let's say I have two columns and they are odds basically, first column is fav odds and second x, and the odds are fav odds/x ... how can I concatenate this to a new vector, to be presented as fav.odds/x and then I will use the previous method to make a frequency table of that.. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 table(values)
 values
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 2 1 1 2 1
```